# Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.1 in sbt?

Tags: scala, jackson, sbt, finagle, circe

I'm getting this error when running TwitterServer from sbt:

```
SEVERE: LoadService: failed to 
instantiate 'com.twitter.finagle.stats.MetricsExporter' 
for the requested service 'com.twitter.finagle.http.HttpMuxHandler'
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Incompatible Jackson version: 2.7.1
```

The 2.7 Jackson dependency is being pulled in transitively from elsewhere (circe).  I thought I could override it to 2.6.7 this way, but it seems to have no effect:

```scala
val jacksonV = "2.6.7"
val `jackson-core` = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % jacksonV
val `jackson-databind` = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % jacksonV
val `jackson-annotations` = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % jacksonV
val `jackson-datatype-jsr310` = "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-jsr310" % jacksonV
dependencyOverrides += `jackson-core`
dependencyOverrides += `jackson-databind`
dependencyOverrides += `jackson-annotations`
dependencyOverrides += `jackson-datatype-jsr310`
```

Any idea why this doesn't override anything?

Comment: Do you mean to be using `%%`? As in `"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" %% "jackson-core" % jacksonV`?

Comment: no, it's not dependent on the scala version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I need to import the library dependencies on those overrides too, even if I'm not using them directly:

```or-tag-here
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    `jackson-databind`,
    `jackson-core`,
    `jackson-annotations`,
    `jackson-datatype-jsr310`,
    // ...
)
```